# Join query with condition if true take by id

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL and I want to know some queries with the condition in Join my question is I need to check some condition and if it is true to take that id with left join or something if false takes another id and join the table

```
select 
 coalesce(supplier.NAME,PARTY2_supplier,PARTY1_supplier)  as Supplier,
     from ACCOUNT acc
     left join RELATIONSHIP r on r.RELATIONSHIP_ID = 2
     left join ORGANIZATION supplier on supplier.ORGANIZATION_ID = acc.SUPPLIER_ID 

if (r.name = 'sales' or r.name = 'purchase'){

        left join ORGANIZATION PARTY2_supplier on PARTY2_supplier.ORGANIZATION_ID = r.PARTY2_ID

}
else {

        left join ORGANIZATION PARTY1_supplier on PARTY1_supplier.ORGANIZATION_ID = r.PARTY1_ID

}
        where acc.ACCOUNT_ID = 34;
```

I need a Proper supplier Name with that account id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but I got an answer we can directly check the condition in on

```
select 
 supplier.NAME  as name,
     from ACCOUNT acc
     left join RELATIONSHIP r on r.RELATIONSHIP_ID = 2
     left join ORGANIZATION supplier on supplier.ORGANIZATION_ID = coalesce(supplier.NAME, if(r.name = 'sales' or r.name = 'purchase', party1.Id, party2.Id) )

        where acc.ACCOUNT_ID = 34;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is: you have to join all tables and use `if` function.

`if` function works in next way:
it will return `yes` for next query `select if(500 < 1000, "yes", "no");`

So with this knowledge you can do something like this:

```
select
if (r.name = 'sales' or r.name = 'purchase', PARTY2_supplier.NAME, PARTY1_supplier.NAME) as Supplier
from ACCOUNT acc
left join RELATIONSHIP r on r.RELATIONSHIP_ID = 2
left join ORGANIZATION supplier on supplier.ORGANIZATION_ID = acc.SUPPLIER_ID 
left join ORGANIZATION PARTY1_supplier on PARTY1_supplier.ORGANIZATION_ID = r.PARTY1_ID
left join ORGANIZATION PARTY2_supplier on PARTY2_supplier.ORGANIZATION_ID = r.PARTY2_ID
where acc.ACCOUNT_ID = 34
;
```